# How to use zero length boolean array in "if"

Tags: java

```
boolean[] booksStatus = new boolean[3];

if(booksStatus.length  = 5){
            System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

This shows me an error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: use double "==" for equality checking. Also, your title is misleading, doesn't match what your code states, just because the elements of the array are not provided with values doesn't mean it is "length 0" in fact the array is actually initialized to the default values. voting to close for typo.

Comment: please specify which error, and which line causes it (the output should tell you)

Comment: are you sure about `=` and not `==` ?

Comment: `=` is assignment operator, `==` is comparison.

Comment: did you understand the answers given?

Comment: yes my friends thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you should be using double equals

```
if(booksStatus.length  == 5){ // single equals is assignment
            System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Second of all, this is always going to be false, as your array length is 3. But maybe you already know this?

Answer (score 2):

use `==` instead of `=` to check equality.

```
boolean[] booksStatus = new boolean[3];

if(booksStatus.length  == 5){
            System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement you use a single `=`. In java syntax you must use a double `==` within an if statement when checking if a value is equal to another value. At least you do with integers or int values.

Comment: using `==` checks if they are equal in shortened ifs as well. It would be better to explain that, as well

Answer (score 0):

comparing integers (array length, the number `5`) in `if`s is done like this:

```
if(bookStatus.length == 5){
    //do things
```

The difference is double `==` and not just `=`. When you use just one, you are actually using the syntax of giving a value (However if you tried `bookStatus.length = 5` outside of the if it would still error, because you cannot change that parameter in that way). In fact, you've used that syntax when you created the array:

```
boolean[] booksStatus = new boolean[3];
                      ^//here
```

Using double equal signs (`==`) is for comparing whether things are **the same**. This works well for specific variable types.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong operator.
Operator `=` is assignment operator.
Operator `==` is equal operator. Its compare is two values are equal each other.

In most cases, in `if` statement you want to use `==` operator. Perhaps you never will need to use `=` (assignment) operator in `if` statement.